# Unshift continuous loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an item from a loop to beginning of my 'storedCompletion' array but for some reason it just continues looping and crashes the browser.

I don't understand why because after it's looped through each object in the array it checks to see if the object id matches up with the list items element id so it should run on one occasion?

JS

```
  if(localStorage) {
    var storedCompletion = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
  }

  for(var f=0; f<storedCompletion.length; f++) {
    if(storedCompletion[f].id == listItem.id) {
      storedCompletion[f].completed = false;
      console.log(storedCompletion);
      storedCompletion.unshift(storedCompletion[f]);
      console.log(storedCompletion);
    }
  }
  localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(storedCompletion));
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing sample data but unshift adds a value to the array your iterating.  Seems like a bad idea.....are you sure thats what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping while `f < storedCompletion.length`, but you are increasing that length inside of your for loop.

Because you are `unshift()`-ing, the item goes to the beginning. That means everything gets push over one. So, when `f++` happens, it looks at the same item. Thus, it'll keep adding forever.

Step through it a couple of times:

```
s = [0]; // s.length === 1, f < s.length
f = 0;
// unshift s, f++
s = [1,0]; // s.length === 2, f < s.length
f = 1; // still points at 0
// unshift s, f++
s = [2,1,0]; // s.length === 3, f < s.length
f = 2; // still points at 0
```

And so on forever. You're getting in an infinite loop.

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but what you might want to do is make a new array to add the new items to, and leave `storedCompletion` alone, then set the new array to `storedCompletion`.

Comment: Thankyou I also didn't realise unshift shifted the other items I thought it removed the first one because I guess that is just shift.

Comment: `unshift()`/`shift()` are equivalent to `push()/pop()`, except on the front instead of the end. If you want to remove an item, you want to use `splice(indexOfItemToRemove, 1)`.